# Directory Api function to list Groups lacks Permission id

Tags: google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk

I need the group permission_id to be able to match certain groups to the files they have access to.

However, the list groups from the directory api DOES NOT return the group's permission id.

It does return the group id but that is not useful for this purpose.

Even the email address value for the permission is null when its a group permission.

So I guess my question is: How do i match a google drive permission to its group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`getIdForEmail`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/getIdForEmail) method of the Drive API.

Comment: that works well. thanks! However this will add to the api calls so is there no better way?

Comment: Not that I know of. Even this method is pretty new. The best solution is to cache the permission id for each group since it will never change.

Comment: Makes sense. Although 'never' is a strong word since if group is deleted and remade, its email will be same but perm id different.